# JavaFx - Share content on lan among same installation

Tags: java, apache, javafx, webserver, shared-directory

I want to create a commercial JavaFx software that need to share some files among the various installation on the same lan. I thought i shall use an http server to create a local repository that all the instances can access through standard IO Java library using ip address. Is there same copyright problem using an Apache server? Do you know a better solution to avoid installing a web server?
NB: there is no concurrency problem, every installation have its own file and just need to read the other ones without race condition problem.

Comment: If this file is "shared" and read-only, why not making this being part of the installation-process? You could make a special "configuration"-wizzard as part of your application, makes you less dependend on that LAN-infrastructure.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i mean: an installation can edit only its own file and read all the others. What did you mean with "special configuration wizard"? Is there same way to share file through various terminals without using lan?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood your scenario, so you want to have a shared location, where local systems store THEIR file, but can read the files from others? Could you elaborate this a bit more? Are we talking about linux-windows-mac mixed environment?

Comment: I like to run it in a non specific environment, my use case is the follow: i have various instances of the same program, each of them on a separate fisic terminal, connected with each other by a lan. My purpose is to create a shared area of memory on the "main terminal", in which other instance can write its own file and read the files of the others. In windows terms: i need a lan shared folder. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: There are several options: 1. you create your own "server" which your clients can connect to (you could embed jetty with your own REST-like interface), 2. using normal network shares and connect as a drive / mount them into the filesystem (linux/mac) ... in terms of cross-system-connection, you should avoid "windows network shares", as they might not be available on the client

Comment: Yeah, it is what i thought, thanks for help. Just one more question: do you know if there is some copyright issue in distributing a software made using jetty?

Comment: Depends on the license ;) http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/licenses.html